# Using memset function in UDP socket

Tags: sockets, server, udp, memset

I have a UDP socket which my client sends an array of integers to the server and the server receives it and store it as a variables. This is happening in an infinite loop. I didn't use any memset function for the buffering in the server side. 
I checked the results on the sever side and everything is being received correctly.

I was wondering if its necessary to use memset at each iteration where I have the recvfrom() function...

Servercode:

```
#define BUFSIZE     10
#define SERVERPORT    "9090" 
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
struct sockaddr_in serveraddr4; /* server's addr */
struct sockaddr_in clientaddr4; /* client addr */
struct hostent *hostp4; /* client host info */
int sockfd4; /* socket */
int portno4; /* port to listen on */
socklen_t clientlen4;
char *hostaddrp4; /* dotted decimal host addr string */
int optval4; /* flag value for setsockopt */
int n4; /* message byte size */
sockfd4 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
portno4 = atoi("8080");
optval4 = 1;
setsockopt(sockfd4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,(const void *)&optval4 , sizeof(int));
bzero((char *) &serveraddr4, sizeof(serveraddr4));
serveraddr4.sin_family = AF_INET;
serveraddr4.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serveraddr4.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)portno4);
int b4=bind(sockfd4, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr4, sizeof(serveraddr4));
clientlen4 = sizeof(clientaddr4);
int buf4[BUFSIZE];

int A;
int B;
int buf4[BUFSIZE];


while(1)
{

    int n4 = recvfrom(sockfd4, buf4, BUFSIZE, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr4, &clientlen4);
    A=buf4[0];B=buf4[1];
    cout<<A<<"  "<<B<<endl;

}
}
```

Comment: No, it is not necessary. If you want to print it *as a string* you could do `buff4[n4] = 0;` ( after testing that n4 >= 0)

Comment: @wildplasser: Thanks! No I don't want to print it as string... But is printing an issue that all of the codes that I have seen are using memset for the buffer inside the loop?  I mean if an array is going to be overwritten in the next iteration why should we set it all to NULL before receiving?

Comment: No, it is just bad style. Wrong kind of defensive programming. IMHO. Instead: **always** check the return value you get from read(), write() recvfrom(), etc. And use it. (in your case: n4 can be -1 {temporally out of resources, (maybe) EAGAIN} )

Comment: @wildplasser If you want to print it as a string you should use `printf("%.*s", n4, buff4)`, rather than sticking nulls in places where they may not even fit.

Comment: @EJP: you are correct, of course. But in case of UDP it is not that hard to use a sufficiently oversized buffer,or use a slightly reduced size (3rd) argument to the recvfrom() call.